# Installing JMagick on Mac to work with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jmagick

I have tried many different ways of installing Imagemagick (by which I understand I should get jmagick) -- brew, binary files, this installer: http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ and so on.

I then try to do as it says here: http://www.rori.me/tech/installing-imagemagick-jmagick-with-eclipse-ubuntu/ , but cannot find a libJMagick.so file--I only have a magick.so file. I tried pointing eclipse to that, but I continue to get the

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JMagick in java.library.path

error when trying to run a small sample program.

Can anyone please help me?